# GNU cp: What's the difference between `--link` and `--reflink=always`?

Tags: cp, hard-link, coreutils, reflink

What's the difference between `--link` and `--reflink=always`?

I use the following command as an `mv` substitute, and I am wondering if using `--reflink` is a better choice.

```
command gcp -r --link --archive --verbose "${opts[@]}" "$@"
# delete the sources manually
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--link` causes `cp` to create hard links instead of copying. Once the “copy” is complete, assuming it’s in the same file system (which is required for hard links), a single instance of the file is present on disk, with two or more directory entries pointing to it. This is the desired external state, *i.e.* the fact that several directory entries point to the same file is visible — they point to the same inode. Changes made through one of the directory entries will be visible through the other as well.

`--reflink=always` requests an optimised copy, if possible. This can take various forms; the most famous is copy-on-write, but it can also be implemented as a server-side copy on networked file systems. Once the copy is complete, it may be the case that a single copy of the data blocks exists on disk, but there are two files, and each directory entry points to a different file. Changes made through one directory entry will not be visible through the other; each file leads a separate life (except for side-effects of the shared data blocks, *e.g.* disk corruption will affect both files).

Put another way, `--link` explicitly requests the creation of new directory entries pointing to the same file, sharing subsequent changes. `--reflink=always` requests the creation of new files, with potential optimisations, and isolated subsequent changes.

As an `mv` alternative, `--link` is more appropriate than `--reflink=always` — it will result in less work for the operating system.