# Any command to exclude all types of files only?

Tags: files, rsync, directory, cp

Does rsync or cp have a command to exclude any type of file besides manually excluding extensions such as `*.txt`, `*.pdf`, `*.jpg` OR setting `-maxdepth` or using `--exclude=dir/*` (used with rsync which excludes ALL SUBFOLDERS under `dir/` and all files as well)?

I'm having some trouble only using `-type d` but either `rsync` and `cp` both require `-r` and when I use `-r` it copies folders recursively no matter if I use any of the exclude commands above and it becomes one big mess.

A related question is here: [cp AND rsync exclude all files of all types from all subdirectories, only keep directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752530/cp-and-rsync-exclude-all-files-of-all-types-from-all-subdirectories-only-keep-d)

[edit]: I found that `rsync -r -t -v --exclude=*.*` works differently than `rsync -r -t -v --exclude=dir/*`

in the first case, it excludes ALL FILE TYPES with `file.extension` essentially becoming the equivalent of `find -type d` version of rsync

in the second case, `rsync -r -t -v --exclude=dir/*`, this basically excludes all files and subfolders under /dir and files and subfolders inside those subfolders etc..making it work kind of like find . -maxdepth 0

Comment: A general idea: 1. `cp -rl` or `cp -r --reflink=always` within the source filesystem to make a "copy" to work with. 2. Remove unneeded files from the "copy". Use whatever means you like (`find`, `rm` with shell globbing etc.). Some tools/commands may be better than others in particular cases and you are not limited to one tool, you can use many commands in sequence to remove many "patterns" one after another. With reflinks you can even use `chmod` or `chattr -i` to protect some exceptions from being removed, without affecting the originals. 3. Copy the "copy" to the actual target location.

Comment: in the cp documentation, 

-l, --link
link files instead of copying

this doesn't make any copy ?

What do you mean reflink=always ? in the documentation it says copy only if the datablock is modified?

Comment: "This doesn't make a copy" – therefore I called it a "copy", in quotes. You can make an actual copy, but it will be a waste of time, diskspace and effort. The point is you make a temporary intermediate "copy" from which you can freely remove unneeded files. Eventually you copy the "copy" in a way that does make a copy. About reflinks: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654482/108618

Comment: im sorry that was a little difficult to follow...

Comment: I just thought of something which might be the problem. When using find . -path ./dir -type d, this only lists all the directories in the path ./dir including it's subfolders and the parent /dir so lets say the directory structure is this:

dir
dir/subfolder1
dir/subfolder2
dir/subfolder3

then using 

find . -path ./dir will only find dir and no subfolder then executing -exec rsync -r -t -v "{}" dest \; will only act on the parent folder but if I use find ./dir -type d then exec will execute it self on the parent folder and all its subfolder and it becomes a recursion of recursion

Comment: I think it would be better if you asked a question explaining what you need to do instead of describing the tool options you think you might need. I really cannot understand what you need from this question. Show an example of the directory structure you start with and then what you want to end up with. Remember that on \*nix, everything is a file, including directories, named pipes, devices and everything else so it isn't really easy to say "exclude all files". If you give a concrete example, however, we can give you a workaround.

Comment: ahh okay I see when u mentioned everything is a file...and I said files...i mean in the windows sense but let me correct my original question

Comment: I still can't work out what you're asking, anmac1789. Please have another go at [editing your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/762254/edit) to explain what you actually want to do, rather than providing guesses at what might work in some unexplained situation. (There's no need to write "edit" - just rewrite your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rsync options to only copy directory tree :

```
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /path/to/src /path/to/dest/
```

Command explained in details there :

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsdosx-copying-directory-structures-trees-rsync/